# Where's the error in this for loop to generate a list of ordered non-repeated combinations?

Tags: python, loops

Given an integer variable n, say 3, I want to obtain these combinations:
[1, 2, 3, 12, 13, 23, 123] and save them in a list.
This is what I wrote:

```
cmb = []
for i in xrange(1,n+1):
    for j in xrange(i,n+1):
        cmb.extend(list(itertools.combinations(xrange(i,n+1),j)))
```

But when I print I get some **unwanted and repeated tuples**:

n = 3 : [(1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2, 3)**, (2, 3)**]

n = 4 : [(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4)**, (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4), (2, 3, 4)**]

n = 5 : ...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The easy way would be to cast them as `set`s.

Comment: what is your logic behind the double loop?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that you changed continuously your input range. For example you took 2 elements from `[1, 2, 3]`, but also 2 elements from `[2, 3]`. You should take your combinations from the same range and just change the number of elements you get at each time. For this purpose, you don't need a double loop:

```
import itertools
cmb = []
for i in xrange(1, n + 1):
    cmb.extend(itertools.combinations(xrange(1, n + 1), i))
```

You can also implement the same thing as:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations
n = 3
print list(chain.from_iterable(
    combinations(xrange(1, n + 1), i) for i in xrange(1, n + 1)
))
```

Output:

```
[(1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
```

Comment: Great explanation. But you probably shouldn't change his xrange to range without mentioning it. Not that building n small ranges is likely to have a performance impact, so it's not a bad change, just an unnecessary one without explanation.

Answer (score 1):

JuniorCompressor has already answered your question, but here is a list comprehension solution with bitmask to filter elements from the original set so that unique elements of the powerset can be generated:

```
>>> sorted([tuple(x for i, x in enumerate([1, 2, 3]) if y & 2**i) 
...         for y in range(1, 8)], key=len)
[(1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
```